# List directories at a specific path as autocomplete options for a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I've got a bash function called **repos** in my **.bash_profile**, for which I'd like to add autocomplete functionality that lists out the contents of a particular directory. I'm trying to achieve this using the `complete` command.

In short, what I've tried:

Created a file called **repos_complete.bash** containing the code below. I've thereafter run `source repos_complete.bash` to make sure it applies to the **repos** script.

Code in `repos_complete.bash`:

```
complete -A directory repos
```

Result so far: If I enter `repos`, and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, it will list out the contents of the current directory. What I'd like however, is for it to list out the contents of another dir, like e.g. `~/source/repos/`.

I tried to to this by replacing the contents of **repos_complete.bash** with the following:

```
 complete -C ls ~/source/repos repos
```

When entering `repos` and <kbd>tab</kbd> now however, I get an error message:

> *Cannot access 'repos': no such file or directory*

It appears to me as if the `-C` (which accepts a command afterward) is interpreting the whole line as a command, including the last "`repos`", instead of just applying the first part (`ls ~/source/repos`) as a command to the function **repos**, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Any tips on the correct way to pass the `ls <some path>` command in the correct way here?

---

*Note: I should point out that this is running in the context of a git bash shell under windows 10, in case that should make any difference.*

Comment: Use completely library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you would need to fill the `COMPREPLY` array. I think this could work:

```
_repos()
{
    local cur;
    local base=~/source/repos/
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur;
    cur="$base$cur"
    _filedir
    COMPREPLY=("${COMPREPLY[@]#$base}")
} && complete -o nospace -F _repos repos
```

If you want to use the `-C` option, you can use this method below. (Note that I have not evaluated it for file-names containing special characters.)

```
_repos()
{
    ( cd ~/source/repos; printf "%s\n" "$2"* )
} && complete -o nospace -C _repos repos
```

Comment: I could not get your first script to work correctly (received an error on the line containing `_filedir`, and to be honest, I'm not able to understand exactly how all of that code works), but your second solution worked perfectly. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: `_filedir` is how bash completion works (at least on ubuntu) for files and directory path completion. (e.g. `ls <tab><tab>` or `cd <tab><tab>`). So, the logic here is: get your typed word. Prefix the base. Let bash-completion do its magix with _filedir. Remove the prefix from the output.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `complete -C` doesn't work as you expect is that `-C` is supposed to take a command which itself takes three arguments. From the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html):

> When the function or command is invoked, the first argument ($1) is the name of the command whose arguments are being completed, the second argument ($2) is the word being completed, and the third argument ($3) is the word preceding the word being completed on the current command line.

So it looks like you need a custom command if you want to use the `-C` form of `complete`.